# Example 8.25 in Linear Algebra Done Right 3rd edition

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm a little confused with this example, the goal is to find a basis with the corresponding eigenvectors of $\mathbb{C}^3$.
The matrix in question of $T\in \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{C}^3)
$ is 
\begin{pmatrix}
6 & 3 & 4\\
0 & 6 & 2\\
0 & 0 & 7
\end{pmatrix}

So that $G(6,T)=\operatorname{null}(T-6I)^2=\operatorname{null}\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 10\\
0 & 0 & 2\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$ and this is not the same as $G(6,T)=span((1,0,0),(0,1,0))$ as said in the book. What is the problem here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no problem. The kernel of $(T-6I)^2$ are the vectors of the form $$\begin{bmatrix}x\\ y\\0\end{bmatrix},$$ which are precisely the span of $$\begin{bmatrix}1\\ 0\\0\end{bmatrix}\ \ \ \ \text{ and } \begin{bmatrix}0\\ 1\\0\end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: I saw your edit the power from 6 to 2, isn't $dim (\mathbb{C}^3)=6$ ?

Comment: No, and that has absolutely no relation with the number that goes there. You already have $(T-6I)^3$$=0$, why would you want to consider the sixth power (which is obviously zero)?